# WMI for identifying file system type of a remote mount

Tags: wmi, ntfs, nfs, cifs

In WMI, how can i find the file system type of a remote mounted file system? i.e. CIFS, NFS, etc...

I can get the mount type from: MSFT_Disk class, but what about remote logicals and their file system?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Win32_MappedLogicalDisk` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa394194.aspx) contains information about mapped drives in Windows.  Specifically, you'd want to query the `FileSystem` property.  Note that if you connect to a share without creating a device name (e.g. `net use \\Server\Share`), it doesn't look like it appears in the results.